# Deleting a specific element in an array of Vectors C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm quite stuck on this function for a c++ program.

**Instructions**
Write a function called RemoveGrades that takes the student array and grade vector as parameters, it asks the user for a valid assignment number, loops through each student, and removes the selected assignment from each student's grades vector.

I've searched a lot about deleting specific elements from vectors but can't seem to figure out how to get vector.erase() to work. I think the issue is that I'm working with a vector of arrays of ints.

**code**

**given**

```
// may be declared outside the main function

const int NUM_STUDENTS =3; 

// may only be declared within the main function

string Students[NUM_STUDENTS] = {"Eric","Stacy","Mark"};

vector <int> grades[NUM_STUDENTS] {
    {10,98,88,99,57},
    {62,80,94,100,93},
    {11,82,28,85,38}
};

void RemoveGrades(string Students[],vector<int> grades[],int numstudents){
    cout<<"Remove assignment"<<endl;
    int assignmentNum;
    assignmentNum=getValidAssignmentNumber();
    for (int index=0;index<numstudents;index++) {
           grades[index].erase(assignmentNum);

    }
}
```

If I put in two arguments in grades[index].erase clion tells me I need one argument, and if I put one it tells me I need two. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

**Error messages**

No matching member function for call to 'erase' candidate function not viable: requires single argument '__position', but 2 arguments were provided

In function 'void RemoveGrades(std::string*, std::vector*, int)':
/cygdrive/c/Users/Ryan Foster/CLionProjects/arrays_and_vectors_second_try/main.cpp:191:56: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector::erase(int&, int&)'
         grades[index].erase(assignmentNum,assignmentNum);

Comment: Please include the compiler error verbatim. Also, note that [`vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) does not take in an index.

Comment: That's not a vector of arrays of ints; it's an array of vectors of ints.

Comment: You could make your own erase method. Since you are using vectors though, you can do `grades[index].erase( grades[index].begin() + assignmentNum );` Still an iterator, but a bit easier.